# VerifyError using Jersey Client

Tags: jersey, client, verifyerror

I have a problem with using the Jersey Client

I am using `jersey-bundle-1.17.1.jar`

When i try to create a Client i throw at Runtime.

```
Client c = Client.create();
```

logcat:

```
01-29 12:46:52.578  13862-13862/com.example.spar.navigationdrawer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.spar.navigationdrawer, PID: 13862
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/sun/jersey/core/impl/provider/entity/MimeMultipartProvider
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:508)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:174)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.__getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:166)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:137)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:256)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:160)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
            at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:342)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:118)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:191)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:187)
            at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:187)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:159)
            at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:669)
            at com.example.spar.navigationdrawer.client.ArticleClient.getArticles(ArticleClient.java:38)
            at com.example.spar.navigationdrawer.MyActivity.<init>(MyActivity.java:72)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```